# Never resolving HTTP Requests from Node+Express API to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building a pretty simple API to do a basic CRUD operations on a local mongo database. The code looks fine for me but somehow the CRUD operations results on a pending request which never ends.

Here the parts of the code:
**spawn.model.js** (Model corresponding to database collection)

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SpawnSchema = Schema({
    Name: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('spawns', SpawnSchema);
```

**spawn.controller.js**

```js
var Spawn = require('../models/Spawn/spawn.model');

exports.getSpawns = function(req, res){
    Spawn.find({}, function(spawns){
        res.send(spawns);
    });
}
```

Here the **spawn.routes.js** file:

```js
var Spawns = require('../controllers/spawn.controller');

module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/list', Spawns.getSpawns);
}
```

And then finally the **server.js** file:

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var properties = require('./config/properties');
var db = require('./config/database');
var app = express();

//configure bodyparser
var bodyParserJSON = bodyParser.json();
var bodyParserURLEncoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });

// call the database connectivity function
db();

// configure app.use()
app.use(bodyParserJSON);
app.use(bodyParserURLEncoded);

// Routes
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({ message: 'Spawns API' });
});

require('./app/routes/spawn.routes')(app);

// intialise server
app.listen(properties.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${properties.PORT} port.`);
})
```

The database file on ./config is the following:

```js
var mongoose =  require('mongoose');
var dbURL = require('./properties').DB;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

module.exports = function(){
    mongoose.connect(dbURL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(){
        console.log('Successfully connected to database');
    });
}
```

And the properties.js on /config is simply an object with the database URL and the port for the express server.

When I try to to a request through Postman to the URL: http://localhost:4000/list the request gets hanged and never resolves. What am I missing?

**PD: SOLVED!
===========**

I needed to update mongoose version on npm cause it was 3.x and needed to be 5.x in order to work well with the new methods.

Comment: Such type of issue happened when a server does not return any response.

Comment: I guess so but I'm trying to see why is not returning any response since the routing seems to be fine and the rest of the code aswell

Answer (score 0):

Update your code little bit, Like this and check

**spwanRoute.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const spawnCntr = require('./speanControllers');

router.get('/list', spawnCntr.getSpawns);

module.exports = router;
```

**spwanUtils.js**

```
const Spawns = require('../models/Spawn/spawn.dao');
const spawnUtils = {};

spawnUtils.getSpawns = (req, res) => {
    try {
        Spawns.get({}, (err, spawns) => {
            if(err){
                return res.status(400).json({ error: err });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({ spawns });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'INTERNAL_EROR' });
    }    
}

module.exports = spawnUtils;
```

Comment: Tried it, but it still remains hanged. And the catch isn't triggered since i'm not recieving any 500 status nor 'Internal Error' message.

Comment: Check your spawn router

Comment: What do you mean? The spawn router file is already copied above, and I think is correct (or at least not able to see what is wrong on it). Following multiples examples on internet just looks the same.. In the main server.js file I'm passing the express.Router() to the spawn router function, and then simply adding the .get('/list') route on it

Comment: I tried to change the route file aswell. By the way, the changes you are proposing are only different ways to do the same thing and without taking in account the ES6 I consider my route file a better implementation since express.router() is declared on the main server.js file and passed into the relative funcions of each route file. Anyways any of the proposals solves the issue yet since those things have nothing to do with a non resolving request I guess if any of this things was wrong I would have seen an error outputing from console or something..

Comment: @MarcHernández Put `app.all('/*', (req, res) => {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Requested URL not found'})
});` after `app.use('/api', router);` and check what will happen

Comment: still the same, no resolving request when i do GET on /api/list